# How to write asyn Task<IEnumarable<Employee>> return Type

Tags: c#, async-await

Here i Wrotecode as async Task> GetCountries() what type of return type i mentioned

Repo.cs

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> GetCountries()
        {
            var x=  from n in _ConnectToDb.Country
                    orderby n.CountryId
                    select n;
            return x.ToList();
        }
```

I called this in My controller as

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Country>> GetCountryRes()
        {
            var x =await ObjRepo.GetCountries();    
            return x;
        }
```

Im getting Error as Deos not contain Defination as GetAwaiter

Comment: Try `return Ok(x.FirstOrDefault());` or change the return type to `Task<IEnumerable<Country>>`

Comment: @SirRufo Here im trying to getting List of data not single Rec

Comment: Sorry, but **your** method signature tells me you want to return a **single** record

Comment: @SirRufo return x.Tolist() mean of Getting Bulk Data im  i R8 Actually inm a Hunior Developer i dont know

Comment: `public async Task<ActionResult<Country>> GetCountryRes()` tells me that it will return a **single** record. If that is not what you want, then write a different method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the GetCountries I have two versions

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> GetCountries()
{
    var x = from n in _ConnectToDb.Country
            orderby n.CountryId
            select n;

    return await Task.FromResult(x.ToList());
}

// I prefer this version 
public Task<IEnumerable<Country>> GetCountries2()
{
    var x = from n in _ConnectToDb.Country
        orderby n.CountryId
        select n;

    return Task.FromResult(x.ToList().AsEnumerable());
}
```

Controller

```
// Here I change the return value to IEnumerable
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Country>>> GetCountryRes()
{
    var x =await ObjRepo.GetCountries();    
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason for `x.ToList().AsEnumerable()` ?

Comment: It won't be an issue. `List` implements `IEnumerable`

Comment: @Sumitraj, This is the error if we do not use AsEnumerable(): Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApp1.Country>>` to `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConsoleApp1.Country>>`

Comment: @Sumitraj, note that the covariance of the generic type parameter of `IEnumerable<T>` is of no concern here, since the return type is not `IEnumerable<T>` but rather `Task<T>`. And the generic type parameter of Task<T> is not covariant...

Comment: @elgonzo Yeah It's because of thread. Thanks, I'll look it into it.

Comment: @Fredy I Have small Doubut as IEnumarable<> //Condition If That failed to Execute Then how can i Handle

Comment: @JOHNMickh are you talking about the query? or if you are talking about `AsEnumerable` this is the method [implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) line 937

Answer (score 2):

```
            public Task<IEnumerable<Country>> GetCountries()
            {
                var x=  from n in _ConnectToDb.Country
                        orderby n.CountryId
                        select n;
                return Task.FromResult(x.ToList());
            }
```

This would be solution in your case. The problem in your code is you should whether retun `Task` or run awaitable method in `GetCountries()`. `Async` keyword itself means nothing, it won't run method asynchronously, it will just allow you to use `await`. So it is redundant in your case

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is edited**

Your method is set to return a single `Country` but your code returns a `IEnumerable<Country>`.

But the problem seems to be solved differently depending on the .Net version.
If you are using .Net Core 2.2 (or later in the future), this should work:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Country>>> GetCountryRes()
{
    var x = await ObjRepo.GetCountries();    
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Nope, you have to return an `ActionResult<Country[]>`

Comment: @SirRufo I think you need to refresh the page

Comment: @einord You are returning the **wrong type** - that is not a refresh problem. `x.ToArray()` will return `Country[]` but expected is `ActionResult<Country[]>` - please compare the types char by char. Got the difference?

Comment: @SirRufo I mean, my example does return an `ActionResult<Country[]>`, so I believe you have to refresh the stackoverflow page to see the edit I did literally a few seconds after my first post when I realized the problem.

Comment: @einord I see `return x.ToArray();` - is that the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

The `async` syntactic sugar in your first method is unnecessary and problematic as you're not awaiting anything. You just need to return a `Task` from your result. But because you're using a LINQ statement (same is true for any LINQ method), the query is not processed until called (and is also re-processed for any subsequent calls), so I recommend evaluating it immediately:

```cs
Task<IEnumerable<Country> GetCountries()
{
  var x = from ...;
  return Task.FromResult(x.ToArray());
}
```